# Using Python and 3 aiohttp to find the URL after redirect when timeout

Tags: python, redirect, aiohttp

I'm currently trying to audit a large number of redirect URL handles to make sure that their destinations are still valid.

I'm using aiohttp to go through the large volume in order to produce a report.

```
try:
    with aiohttp.Timeout(timeout):
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return {"Handle URL": url,
                    "Status Code": resp.status,
                    "Redirects": resp.url != url,
                    "Resolving URL": resp.url,
                    "Success": resp.status == 200,
                    "Message": ""}
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return {"Handle URL": url,
                "Success": False,
                "Message": "Handle server timed out. >{} seconds".format(timeout)}
```

For the most part, this has been fine for identifying which URL redirect no longer sends to a valid URL. However, I'd really like to know the final address where times out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to do it is disabling redirects by `allow_redirects=False` and performing redirections manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(URL, allow_redirects=False) as response:
        Location = str(response).split("Location': \'")[1].split("\'")[0]
            return Location
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here.

Comment: The final url from the redirect is output in the response and the Location variable is just extracting that part from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary anymore to parse that string for a Location. Here is a small example.

Local flask server with a redirect:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/redirect')
def redir():
    return redirect('/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

aiohttp request to that redirect:

```
# coding: utf-8
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def fetch(URL):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(URL, allow_redirects=False) as response:
            print(response.url, response.real_url, 'location' in str(response).lower())

        async with session.get(URL, allow_redirects=True) as response:
            print(response.url, response.real_url, 'location' in str(response).lower())

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/redirect"

async def main():
    await fetch(local_url)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

prints:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/redirect http://127.0.0.1:5000/redirect True
http://127.0.0.1:5000/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/ False
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientResponse.real_url), the difference between `url` and `real_url` is that real_url is the raw string of the original request, not stripped.